# Ring epimorphisms and finiteness assumptions

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-rings

Let $f : A\to B$ be a ring epimorphism. It is well-known that, under the extra assumption that $A$ and $B$ are commutative, then $f$ makes $B$ a finitely-generated $A$-module implies that $f$ must be surjective. I guess that, without commutativity hypothesis, if one strenghtens the finiteness assumption, the surjectivity conclusion should remain true. For example, if $A$ and $B$ are finite-dimensional algebras over a field $K$ and $f$ is $K$-linear, does it hold? More generally, if $B$ is of finite length over $A$ (both right and left, let us say), does it hold?